# Unable to install certain Nuget packages in VS2012 - Appears to be Networking Issue

Tags: ninject, visual-studio-2012, nuget, firewall, nlog

I have installed VS2012 and having some issues installing certain Nuget packages.

When i create a new MVC4 project all the default packages seem to install ok.

I can add some packages - ELMAH for example, but when i try and install some packages it just wont have it and im stuck.

The error message i get is:

Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

I have tried some different Nuget sources:

https://nuget.org/api/v2/
http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/

The packages im specifically having problems with are Ninject, Ninject.MVC3 and NLog

UPDATE:

Ive used the package manager GUI for these tests.  The console doesnt work either.

I've utilised fiddler to inspect the network traffic and it appears things are going wrong at the following point:

CONNECT az320820.vo.msecnd.net:443 HTTP/1.1

A tunnel is setup to az320820.vo.msecnd.net:443 and then once established the following call is made down the tunnel:

GET /packages/Newtonsoft.Json.4.5.8.nupkg HTTP/1.0 And thats where it all stops and nothing else happens until it times out.

DNS resolutions for the network name both resolve the same IP's at both sites.

I can telnet to the DNS name on port 443.

There are some similar old issues on codeplex where the network name wasnt found but everything is resolving OK here. Its at the point that the package is requested down the tunnel that things just stop.

- FURTHER UPDATE

If i enter this URL in a browser on my laptop: http://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/packages/NHibernate.3.3.1.4000.nupkg which is the package for nhibernate the url is unknown.  However if i try it from other machines on the same network (all with DHCP identical settings) then it works.  So it points to an issue with my machine. However if i put my laptop on another network it downloads fine!

Its got me completely confused as to what the issue could be.

Something else is that the link works on another PC (in a browser) but the package wont download via Nuget in VS2010.

Can anyone help or give me any pointers because im pulling my hair out now.

Comment: Have you eliminated network and server issues?

Comment: Just to add and i've done lots  of searching around and cant find this error message linked to Nuget anywhere.  Its odd its only happening with certain packages.

Comment: @Richard - well some packages install fine and everything else seems to be working ok.  Its just specific packages that dont seem to install. As noted ive tried different Nuget Repos so not sure what is the issue.

Comment: The reason I ask is "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host." is the description for error WSAECONNRESET which socket APIs return when the connection is unexpectedly broken.

Comment: I take my laptop over to the other office and try on the network over there as it has a completely separate broadband connection. Ive also tried disabling my firewall and still get the same issues.

Comment: Well thats puzzled me. Its worked fine over at the other office.  Also testedt using VS2010 in the office with the problem and thats got the same issue. What could be blocking the request? We have all outbound ports open so not sure what could be the problem.  Could it  be a DNS issue? Really odd it works for some packages and not others.

Comment: Please update Q with 1. this is related to a specific network. 2. how you are using NuGet: GUI, package manager console, or NuGet.exe. (I've also voted to move this to [SU] as that is a better fit since this is not really a development question.)

Comment: After fetching my laptop back over to the site with the issue it worked fine however i couldn't now access any of the network shares. I then refreshed my IP config, flushed dns and connected to the server but still couldn't gain access to the shares. So i restarted the machine and now everything working again. Odd... very odd! Still got another machine with the same issue so its not isolated to my laptop. Just restarting that one too to see if it cures it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is a (local?) networking issue.

Normal network diagnostics need to be applied.

Remember anything from a local office proxy to a routing issue somewhere between you and `nuget.org` can break things even if your own machine is fine.

Comment: Thanks Richard (new to stack overflow so please correct me if im doing anything wrong here).  The laptop working back at the site with the issue was a red herring as it looks like the package files were coming from a local cache.  If i try another package i'm getting the failure again.  <br/><br/>Not sure what to test for with respect to what isn't working with Nuget - everything else seems to be functioning OK - web, ftp, mail etc..  Are there any specific things i can test - does Nuget use any special ports? (PS: I cant get line breaks working in my comments??? tried <br/> and 2 spaces)

Comment: @dgreenuk Please see my comment on the Q to update the Q: rewrite saying more precisely what works, what doesn't and what you have tried. Precise is key: small differences (which NuGet interface) may well be significant. Also please flag your question to ask a mod to move it to [SU].

Comment: Ok ive utilised fiddler to inspect the network traffic and it appears things are going wrong at the following point:

CONNECT az320820.vo.msecnd.net:443 HTTP/1.1

A tunnel is setup to az320820.vo.msecnd.net:443 and then once established the following call is made down the tunnel:

GET /packages/Newtonsoft.Json.4.5.8.nupkg HTTP/1.0

And thats where it all stops and nothing else happens until it times out.

Any ideas where to go from here?

Comment: DNS resolutions for the network name both resolve the same IP's at both sites.  I can telnet to the DNS name on port 443.  There are some similar old issue son codeplex where the network name wasnt found but everything is resolving OK here.  Its at the point that the package is requested down the tunnel that things just stop.